# Create a survey in sharepoint 2010 where question text is from external content type

Tags: external-content-type, survey-list

I have a small issue. I need to create a survey page in SharePoint 2010. This page needs to have dynamic number of questions where text values for this questions are retrieved from SQL Server database table.

Any pointers on how to start developing my solution?